# Aggregating in SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Conversion_Date     User_Name     Last_Date_Touch     Touch_Count
      7/15/2017             A           6/17/2017               1
      7/16/2017             B           6/24/2017               2
      7/19/2017             A           6/20/2017               1
      7/19/2017             C           6/29/2017               1
```

I want to get the sum of `Touch_Count` from the last 30 days for each `Conversion_Date` by `User_Name` in SQL.

The only thing I could think of at first was to figure out the time window for each conversion date going back 30 days and then I'm not sure how to aggregate this to get the final result.

First it was adding the 30 day window below:

```
Conversion_Date     User_Name     Last_Date_Touch     Touch_Count   30_Days_Ago
      7/15/2017             A           6/17/2017               1     6/15/2017      
      7/16/2017             B           6/24/2017               2     6/16/2017
      7/19/2017             A           6/20/2017               1     6/19/2017
      7/19/2017             C           6/29/2017               1     6/19/2017
```

Then I need to aggregate it so that it looks like this:

```
Conversion_Date     User_Name     Last_Date_Touch     Touch_Count     SUM(Last30daysbyconversiondate)
      7/15/2017             A           6/17/2017               1      5
      7/16/2017             B           6/24/2017               2      5
      7/19/2017             A           6/20/2017               1      4
      7/19/2017             C           6/29/2017               1      4
```

The last two were 4 because the last_date_touch value of 6/17/2017 was not in the 30 day window for 7/19/2017, so that touch_count was excluded making the total count 4 in this case for the last two rows.

Any help would be great if you know how to do this in SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be obtainable with a self join

```
select
    a.User_Name
    ,a.Conversion_Date
    ,sum(b.Touch_Count) as SumOver30Days
from
    SomeTable a
    left join
        SomeTable b on
        b.User_Name = a.User_name
        --and b.Conversion_Date <= a.Conversion_Date
        --and b.Conversion_Date >= dateadd(day,-30,a.Conversion_Date)
        and cast(b.Conversion_Date as date) <= cast(a.Conversion_Date as date) 
        and cast(b.Conversion_Date as date) >= cast(dateadd(day,-30,a.Conversion_Date) as date)
group by a.User_Name, a.Conversion_Date
```

Comment: I would have never thought to do a self-join...genius. Thanks!

Comment: No worries @NickKnauer  happy to help

Comment: Will this still work if the conversion date column is in the form of a timestamp such as '2017-07-15 01:34:29'? @scsimon

Comment: Yes @NickKnauer but when dealing with DateTimes, it's wise to cast it to the date to not lose those partial days. `and cast(b.Conversion_Date as date) <= cast(a.Conversion_Date as date) and cast(b.Conversion_Date as date) >= cast(dateadd(day,-30,a.Conversion_Date) as date)`

Comment: Should I add that new part to the query or replace the `and b.Conversion_Date >= dateadd(day,-30,a.Conversion_Date)` with the new part? Reason I am asking is because the numbers aren't aligning in my example....still trying to figure out if it is something I am doing wrong on my end.

Comment: yea, replace it. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Just want to follow up with this. Is this query just taking the last 30 days from the conversion date but not taking into account the last date touch? So for example, if I obtain 30 days prior to the conversion date, the output would be a conversion date (not a last date touch) of 30 days. Therefore, there could be clicks that could be more than 30 days back.

Comment: I also put this in a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180356/aggregating-in-sql-multiple-criteria