# Aggregating in SQL - Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, amazon-redshift

This is a follow-up question to [Aggregating in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722049/aggregating-in-sql)

I have a table below.

```
Conversion_Date     User_Name     Last_Date_Touch     Touch_Count
      7/15/2017             A           6/17/2017               1
      7/16/2017             B           6/24/2017               2
      7/19/2017             A           6/20/2017               1
      7/19/2017             C           6/29/2017               1
```

Grouped by `Conversion_Date` and `User_Name`, what is the sum of the `Touch_Count` looking back 30 days from the `Conversion Date` **but at the same time keeping the Last_Date_Touch within that 30 day window of the Conversion_Date**.

For example, if I look back 30 days from the Conversion_Date = 7/19/2017, I cannot just take the sum of the Touch_Count for the 30 day window like below because it will include the first row which has a Last_Date_Touch out of the 30 day window of the conversion date.

This was the attempt, but I don't think it takes into account the `Last_Date_Touch` being in that 30 day window.

```
select
     a.User_Name
    ,a.Conversion_Date
    ,sum(b.Touch_Count) as SumOver30Days
from
    SomeTable a
    left join
        SomeTable b on
        b.User_Name = a.User_name
        and cast(b.Conversion_Date as date) <= cast(a.Conversion_Date as date) 
        and cast(b.Conversion_Date as date) >= cast(dateadd(day,-30,a.Conversion_Date) as date)
group by a.User_Name, a.Conversion_Date
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is you expected O/P? & Which DBMS?

Comment: I think you just need to add this to the join: `and cast(b.Last_Date_Touch as date) >= cast(dateadd(day,-30,a.Conversion_Date) as date)`

Comment: What *Last_Date_Touch* do you want returned? Either add it in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregate with min or max? And does your RDBMS change from SQL Server as tagged in linked question.

Comment: @scsimon yeah that makes more sense, thanks for the help!

Comment: No sweat @NickKnauer